# Why can Container::getInstance() return an application class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, static, static-methods

I am I'm wondering why the `Container::getInstance()` can return a application class.

For example:

I want to make a hash str, I want to know how they work：

```
app('hash')->make('password');
```

and I found the source code in laravel ：

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

```
if (! function_exists('app')) {
    /**
     * Get the available container instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $make
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
    {
        if (is_null($make)) {
            return Container::getInstance();
        }

        return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);

    }
}
```

I dont know  what the `Container::getInstance()` will return, then I `dd（Container::getInstance()）` and I know it will can return an application class, but I dont know how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm a little bit late with my answer, but anyway.

Description is current as of Laravel framework version 5.3.24.

**Why** calling `app()`, that then calls `Container::getInstance()` returns object, instance of Application?
For example, why

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    var_dump(app());
});
```

outputs:

```
object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)
...
```

**Because...** And here we have to go step by step though it to understand everything.

1. User initiates a web request. The request is processed by `/public/index.php`
2. `/public/index.php` contains the following:

   ```
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
   ```
3. `/bootstrap/app.php` has the following lines:

   ```
   $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
       realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
   );
   ```
4. When an $app object is instantiated, the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class constructor is called.

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`

```
    class Application extends Container implements ...
    {
        // ...
        public function __construct($basePath = null)
        {
            // 5. constructor triggers the following method:
            $this->registerBaseBindings();
            // ...
        }
        // ...
        protected function registerBaseBindings()
        {
            // 6. which then triggers the following:
            static::setInstance($this);
            // 7. Important! $this points to class Application here
            // and is passed to Container
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

8. `static::setInstance($this);` refers us to `class Container`, because `class Application extends Container`

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php`

```
    class Container implements ...
    {
        // ...
        // 11. $instance now contains an object,
        // which is an instance of Application class
        protected static $instance;
        // ...
        public static function setInstance(ContainerContract $container = null)
        {
            // 9. $container = Application here, because it has been passed
            // from class Application while calling static::setInstance($this);
            // 10. Thus, static::$instance is set to Application here
            return static::$instance = $container;
        }
        // ...
    }
```

---

12. Now, suppose, we have written the following lines in our routes file.
    `/routes/web.php`

    ```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd(app()); // 13. We a calling an app() helper function
    });
    ```

14 Calling app() leads us to
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

```
    // ...
    /** @return mixed|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
    function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
    {
        // 15. $make is null, so this is the case
        if (is_null($make)) {
            // 16. The following static method is called:
            return Container::getInstance();
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
```

17. Now we are back in our Container class
    `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php`

    ```
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        // 18. Important!
        // To this point static::$instance is NOT null,
        // because it has already been set (up to "step 11").
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static; // Thus, we skip this.
        }
        // 19. static::$instance is returned
        // that contains an object,
        // which is an instance of Application class
        return static::$instance;
    }
    ```

**Some important notes for steps 16-19.**

Important note 1!

[Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of the class.

Important note 2!

`static::$instance = new static;` is NOT related to calling our app() function in step 13. And was somewhat misleading for me at first...

But just to note, it makes use of [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Comment: 2021 - Thank you!! I was reading the code of Laravel step by step to get to know how everything's working - But I missed/skipped it. Everything makes sense now :D

Answer (score 0):

The Application class (Illuminate\Foundation\Application) extends the Container class. This is the core of the framework and allows all the dependency injection magic, and it follows a Sigleton pattern, this means that when you request the Application object (with the `app()` helper function, or more internally `Container::getInstance()`) anywhere in your code you get the same global instance.

Without getting to complex: this let's you bind any class into that Container instance:

```
app()->bind('MyModule', new MyModuleInstace());
```

So then you can "resolve" that class out of the container with:

```
app()->make('MyModule);
```

But remember there are several methods to do this, with different pattern targets, this is just a basic demonstration of the concept.

Comment: thank you for you help,i am not sure i got it ,because i cant find the container class will return the global instance even it was instanced when it only has `app()`, i know the make function or the bind function can help me resolve this,but its only has `app()`,no` ->make` or` ->bind`, and i found `$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;` in `public/index.php`,what's the different between them？ is it the same? but they are different by syntax,thanks